# How to get id from model which return array and pass to the controller function as parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

When i pass the id from model to controller it says array cannot be convert to string.. But my problem is i want all the post and fetch the comment according to the post.. I am unable to do this

```
                       public function getPosts()
                           {
                                   $sql="SELECT d.*,u.username,u.image FROM tbl_discussion as d join user as u
                                   on d.user_id=u.user_id order by date desc";
                                   $query=$this->db->query($sql);
                                   return $query->result();
                           }

                           public function getReplies($post_id=NULL)
                           {

                                   //$sql="SELECT r.*,u.username FROM tbl_replies as r 
                                   //join user as u on r.user_id=u.user_id 

                                   //join tbl_discussion as d on d.discussion_id=r.discussion_id  where r.discussion_id='$post_id' order by date desc";
                                 $sql="SELECT r.*,u.username FROM tbl_replies as r 
    join user as u on r.user_id=u.user_id 
    join tbl_discussion as d on d.discussion_id=r.discussion_id  where r.discussion_id='$post_id'order by date desc";


                              $query=$this->db->query($sql);
                                     if($query->num_rows()>0){
                                           foreach ($query->result() as $data){
                                               $row[]=$data;
                                           }
                                           return $row;
                                       }
                           }
public function getId(){
        $sql="select discussion_id from tbl_discussion";
        $query=  $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

In controller

```
 public function index()
{



    $id=$this->kishan->getid();
    $data1['agros']=$this->kishan->getNoticAgros();
    $data2['farms']=$this->kishan->getNoticFarmers();
    $data3['members']=$this->kishan->getNoticMembers();
    $data4['ngoss']=$this->kishan->getNoticNgos();
    $data5['followups']=$this->kishan->getNoticFollowUp();
    $data6['all']=$this->kishan->getNoticAll();
    $data7['posts']=$this->kishan->getPosts();
    $data8['replies']=$this->kishan->getReplies($id);
    $data9['page']='discussion';
    $this->load->view('admin/home',array_merge($data1,$data2,$data3,$data4,$data5,$data6,$data7,$data8,$data9));
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No error just dont know how to get id of each post as per wanted

Comment: Check my updated answer. Did you get $row['id']?

Comment: where is your update answer

Comment: I have added r.*,u.*,d.* in query to get data of all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WHERE statement like in the comment.

```
$sql="SELECT * from tbl_replies as r
    LEFT JOIN user as u ON r.user_id=u.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_discussion as d ON r.discussion_id = d.discussion_id
    WHERE r.discussion_id='" . $post_id . "'";
```

I'm not sure if I understand your Problem fully, but lets assume $aPostIds is an array filled with the desired ids:

```
// Escape all values
$aPostIdsEscaped=array()
foreach($aPostIds as $postId) 
    $aPostIdsEscaped[]=mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $postId);

// Turn array into IN clause
$sql="SELECT * from tbl_replies as r
    LEFT JOIN user as u ON r.user_id=u.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_discussion as d ON r.discussion_id = d.discussion_id
    WHERE r.discussion_id IN ('" . implode("', '", $aPostIdsEscaped) . "'";
```

Comment: i dont know how to get id from post as per there are multilple post $data7['posts']=$this->kishan->getPosts();
  $data8['replies']=$this->kishan->getReplies(3);

Answer (score 1):

Write your query as below:-

```
$sql="SELECT r.*,u.*,d.* from tbl_replies as r
      LEFT JOIN user as u ON r.user_id=u.user_id 
      LEFT JOIN tbl_discussion as d ON r.discussion_id = d.discussion_id";
```

Hope it will help you :)